# How can I see the code generated for a Razor Page when using Asp.Net Core?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

With Asp.Net it was easy to see the code generated by the Razor View Engine: Add a compile error and the error page will give access to the source of the Razor Page.

This changed with Asp.Net Core, which I read somewhere creates the code in memory and does not allow access to that code easily.

Question: Someone knows a trick how to access generated Razor source code with Asp.Net Core?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following class to your ASP.NET Core MVC project:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class CustomCompilationService : DefaultRoslynCompilationService, ICompilationService
{
    public CustomCompilationService(ApplicationPartManager partManager, 
        IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions> optionsAccessor, 
        IRazorViewEngineFileProviderAccessor fileProviderAccessor, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
        : base(partManager, optionsAccessor, fileProviderAccessor, loggerFactory)
    {
    }

    CompilationResult ICompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo fileInfo, 
        string compilationContent)
    {
        return base.Compile(fileInfo, compilationContent);
    }
}
```

Override the `ICompilationService` added by MVC with the above class;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<ICompilationService, CustomCompilationService>();
}
```

Set a break point on the `Compile` method of `CustomCompilationService` and view `compilationContent`.

[image]

## Notes

View lookups are case sensitive. If your controller routing seeks a view named `Index` (`Index.cshtml`) but you've named your view file `index` (`index.cshtml`), you'll receive an exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found.

Comment: What about ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Comment: @SinglePackAbs yep, there are neither DefaultRoslynCompilationService nor ICompilationService.

Answer (score 5):

Artificial Stupidity provided the correct answer for ASP.NET core 1.x. For version **2.0** of the framework, one can instead use a custom razor template engine:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language;

public class CustomMvcRazorTemplateEngine : MvcRazorTemplateEngine
{
  public CustomMvcRazorTemplateEngine(RazorEngine engine, RazorProject project) : base(engine, project)
  { }

  public override RazorCSharpDocument GenerateCode(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
  {
    RazorCSharpDocument razorCSharpDocument = base.GenerateCode(codeDocument);
    // Set breakpoint here for inspecting the generated C# code in razorCSharpDocument.GeneratedCode
    // The razor code can be inspected in the Autos or Locals window in codeDocument.Source._innerSourceDocument._content 
    return razorCSharpDocument;
  }
}
```

Then override the `RazorTemplateEngine` of the framework:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();
  services.AddSingleton<RazorTemplateEngine, CustomMvcRazorTemplateEngine>();
}
```

---

In version **2.1** of ASP.NET Core, the `RazorTemplateEngine` seems to be legacy, and the above mechanism does not work anymore. The changes may have to do with the move towards precompilation of razor views, but since I am not involved in the development, I can only guess at the developers' motives.

I would now recommend inspecting the precompiled views in the `**.Views.dll` generated at build or publish time, depending on your project settings. I personally use Telerik's JustDecompile for this purpose.

If you really need to have a programmatic solution, you can hook into the `RazorProjectEngine` with a custom phase:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language;

namespace Econet.PAG.UI
{
  internal class DebugRazorEnginePhase : IRazorEnginePhase
  {
    public RazorEngine Engine { get; set; }

    public void Execute(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
    {
      RazorCSharpDocument razorCSharpDocument = codeDocument.GetCSharpDocument();
      // Set breakpoint here for inspecting the generated C# code in razorCSharpDocument.GeneratedCode
      // The razor code can be inspected in the Autos or Locals window in codeDocument.Source._innerSourceDocument._content 
    }
  }
}
```

and register it in the creation of the `RazorProjectEngine`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton(s =>
    {
      var fileSystem = s.GetRequiredService<RazorProjectFileSystem>();
      var projectEngine = RazorProjectEngine.Create(RazorConfiguration.Default, fileSystem, builder =>
      {
        RazorExtensions.Register(builder);

        // Roslyn + TagHelpers infrastructure
        var metadataReferenceFeature = s.GetRequiredService<LazyMetadataReferenceFeature>();
        builder.Features.Add(metadataReferenceFeature);
        builder.Features.Add(new CompilationTagHelperFeature());

        // TagHelperDescriptorProviders (actually do tag helper discovery)
        builder.Features.Add(new DefaultTagHelperDescriptorProvider());
        builder.Features.Add(new ViewComponentTagHelperDescriptorProvider());

        builder.Phases.Add(new DebugRazorEnginePhase());
      });
}
```

Note that except for the line adding the custom phase, the code inside `AddSingleton` is copied from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcRazorMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.AddRazorViewEngineServices(IServiceCollection services)` in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor` sources.

Comment: I tries this in ASP.NET Core 2.1 but it does not hit the breakpoint. Is there a change for 2.1? This is in the standard Web Application (i.e. Razor Pages)

Answer (score 4):

In a simple Console Application:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sourceDocument = RazorSourceDocument.Create("Hello world", "");
        var codeDocument = RazorCodeDocument.Create(sourceDocument);

        var engine = RazorEngine.Create();
        engine.Process(codeDocument);

        var csharpDocument = codeDocument.GetCSharpDocument();
        var csharp = csharpDocument.GeneratedCode;
        Console.WriteLine(csharp);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
#pragma checksum "" "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}" "7b502c3a1f48c8609ae212cdfb639dee39673f5e"
// <auto-generated/>
#pragma warning disable 1591
namespace Razor
{
    #line hidden
    public class Template
    {
        #pragma warning disable 1998
        public async override global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync()
        {
            WriteLiteral("Hello world");
        }
        #pragma warning restore 1998
    }
}
#pragma warning restore 1591
```